# How to pass value from one action to another action having same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I am developing an application in MVC3. and i am stuck at one place. Everytime when control goes to `IIndex1` action its argument value has become 0. But it should be same as value in `IIndex` action argument. I have used session, ViewBag, ViewData but my problem is remains. Please suggest me.

```
        public ActionResult GetMDN(string msisdn)
        {
            number = msisdn.Substring(0, msisdn.IndexOf('$'));
            if (number.ToLower() != "unknown" && number.Length == 12)
            {
                number = number.Remove(0, 2);
            }
            Session["msdresponse"] = number;
            Session["moptr"] = msisdn.Substring(msisdn.LastIndexOf('$') + 1);
            number = msisdn;
            int sngid=int.Parse(ViewData["isongid"].ToString());
            return RedirectToAction("IIndex1", new { iid = sngid });
        }

        public ActionResult IIndex(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.isongid = id;
            ViewData["isongid"] = id;
            Response.Redirect("http:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            return RedirectToAction("GetMDN");
        }

        public ActionResult IIndex1(int iid)
        {

        }
```

Comment: is this code not working for you?

Comment: No..... Thats why I have posted here. Main issue is that when control pass from GetMDN action to IIndex1 Action, argument of Int iid hase became 0. But it should be same as whatever value have in IIndex action argument

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use TempData.You can pass every types of data between to action, whether they are in same controller or not. Your code should be something like it:

```
    public ActionResult GetMDN(string msisdn)
    {
        int sngid=10;

        TempData["ID"] = sngid;

        return RedirectToAction("IIndex");
    }

    public ActionResult IIndex()
    {

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["ID"]);// id will be 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use TempData instead of ViewData/ViewBag to store data that should persist after redirect.
ViewData/ViewBag allow to pass value from controller to view.

Something to read on this subject:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-cplusViewBagplusandplusTem

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use  TempData["name"] = variableToPass;